# Scan Biz Cards with Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, api, http, cordova

Is it possible to scan business cards with phonegap and fetch the contact details from that card ? I couldn't find anything on google, so posting it here.

Can anyone suggest some good http api to convert business card image to contact details.

Thanks

Comment: Me too have the same doubt....can anyone help us ?

Comment: You should give a try to Covve Bussiness Card Scan API: https://covve.com/business-card-scanning-api/. The quality of the result is great in lot's of languages. You can check a comparison analysis of similar services here https://www.capacitorpartners.com/post/an-extensive-comparison-of-business-card-scanners-camcard-abbyy-covve-scan-bizconnect. [Disclosure] I'm part of the team developing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found some APIs. Here are the results of my R&D on business cards scanning:

There is no direct plugin or method available to extract contact information from a business card. You can use several APIs available in the market. Some of them are:

1. **Full Contact** : http://www.fullcontact.com/developer/
2. **Shape API** :  http://bcrtest.shapeservices.net/
3. **Cam Card API** : https://dev.camcard.com/
4. **Evernote API** : https://dev.evernote.com/doc/

Remember these APIs are not freeware.